How to install a second ground bar on a Square D Homeline subpanel
I’m installing a new BXH21B Homeline Square D subpanel for my basement.
I want to have ground bars on both sides of the panel, so that each circuit lands conveniently on one side. I do not want each circuit’s ground wire running around the perimeter of the panel if the breaker is on the opposite side from the ground bar.
The panel came with two ground bars but only two screws. Once I find the correct screws to mount it to the panel on the right side can I install it and simply connect the two bars with a 10 gauge unsheathed copper wire?
I can’t find a manual for this panel or clarity elsewhere online.


What's going on with the feeder conduit entry? Is that a female adapter used in place of a locknut?

Nah. That’s a subpanel meter. Not secured yet. It’s a little donut that measured energy usage.

what's with the current transformer (black donut): it's only measuring one phase.

I think @NoSparksPlease is asking about how the conduit is secured to the panel box.


The panel came with two ground bars but only two screws. Once I find the correct screws to mount it to the panel on the right side can I install it and simply connect the two bars with a 10 gauge unsheathed copper wire?

I have the exact same Square-D panel. What's not intuitive is you use only one screw per grounding bar.
The panel has these stamped divits on either side, with a single screw hole between them. That's where you attach your ground bars to the panel. Here's where you would attach the other grounding bar.


And looking at the picture, the first bar is installed wrong. It should be reinstalled correctly.

The panel labeling has a list of compatible accessories. Among them are a number of ground bars. Now, see the nubs about 3" apart with a hole halfway between them?  Those are intended to fit those accessory ground bars.  The holes are tapped -32. Looks like they gave you one very short bar, but wholly inadequate for a panel this size. Feel free to populate as many as you like.
They use -32 thread pitch screws (probably 8-32) and as such they have 2 full thread engagements in the panel metal. That makes them a legal grounding path and no grounding strap is needed to tie the ground bar to ground.
Feel free to improvise other sites (e.g. at the top) and use other manufacturer's ground rods, but if you do, use ones with 2 screws, since the nubs won't match up. You would need to drill-tap your own holes.
I'm a huge fan of having every hot+neutral long enough to reach every space in the panel. However grounds just need to reach the nearest ground bar.
Also, I'm not sure what's up with the pipe sticking into the panel, but that's not how you terminate conduit.  Before the inspector sees it, replace it with a proper PVC fitting and a conduit nut.
If you are concerned with breaker spaces, it appears that "box" also supports a 24-space interior (and possibly a 30-32 space Type QO interior). If you want to do that upgrade, find a panel with the same "box number" and swap interiors.  You'd need to do that in the next 5 years or so before they change styles.

Yes, you should be able to add a second ground bar on the other side. Connecting it to the first ground bar is not a bad idea but may not actually be required as the entire box is ground - e.g., if you have circuits grounded via metal conduit to a metal box then they don't even need a ground wire in that box.
But more importantly, if you cut off the non-metallic cable sheath close to the entrance (I found a number of sources for leaving 1/4" of the sheath inside the box, but not for more than that) then you separate the hot, neutral and ground wires at the entrance - top in this image but could be side or bottom as well. In this example, except if you have a cable coming in on the right side, the ground wire really doesn't have to travel much farther to get to the left ground bar than to the right ground bar, even if the hot and neutral are going to the right side bus bars.
Also keep in mind that often ground bars can take multiple wires per screw, even though that is not the case for neutral and hot. Check your panel label to find out the details as it often depends on wire size.
